# Visualizing Neural Network Architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visualization

I have tried to visualize the architecture of my neural network (see code below).  [I want to get something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL3p0.png) in terms of visualization.

but I didn't manage to do it. What package should I use or can anyone illustrate what would my network result in?

This is the code for my network:

```
new_img_size = 128  
nbr_img = 3 
delta_t = 10  
min_pred = 10  

image1 = Input(shape=(new_img_size, new_img_size, 3))
image2 = Input(shape=(new_img_size, new_img_size, 3))

y1 = BatchNormalization()(image1)
y1 = Flatten()(y1)
y1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(y1)
cnn1 = Model(inputs=image1, outputs=y1)

input_sequence1 = Input(shape=(nbr_img, new_img_size, new_img_size, 3))

lstm1 = TimeDistributed(cnn1)(input_sequence1)
lstm1 = LSTM(1024, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(lstm1)
lstm1 = Dense(48, activation='relu')(lstm1)

y2 = BatchNormalization()(image2)
y2 = Flatten()(y2)
y2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(y2)
cnn2 = Model(inputs=image2, outputs=y2)

input_sequence2 = Input(shape=(nbr_img, new_img_size, new_img_size, 3))

lstm2 = TimeDistributed(cnn2)(input_sequence2)
lstm2 = LSTM(1024, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(lstm2)
lstm2 = Dense(48, activation='relu')(lstm2)

merged = concatenate([lstm1, lstm2])

mlp = Dense(96, activation='relu')(merged)
mlp = Dense(48, activation='relu')(merged)
mlp = Dense(int(min_pred/delta_t), activation='linear')(mlp)
model = Model(inputs=[input_sequence1, input_sequence2], outputs=mlp)

model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
```

Thank you for your help

###### EDIT

I have tried both
`tf.keras.utils.plot_model`
and netron and both give me this

[image]

I do find this useful but since I have a layer of TimeDistributed, I would like to see this in my plot as well. I don't want to see just the name "Time distributed", I would like to see how this layer is creating seperate CNN layers for each input image.

Comment: try tensorboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plot_model` to programmatically visualize the architecture https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=False, show_dtype=False,
    show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB', expand_nested=False, dpi=96,
    layer_range=None
)
```

Or, you can use netron to visualize the weight of the model including the architecture.

ref: https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron